How can I inject MatBottomSheetRef into the childComponent that is loaded inside the Bottom-Sheet?
In the official angular material component documentation it says

Any component contained inside of a bottom sheet can inject the MatBottomSheetRef as well.

I want to call sheetRef.dismiss() from within the component that I load inside the Bottom-Sheet.
Is this possible? And how can I do such an injection as suggested above?

(this worked for me)
You can inject the MatBottomSheetRef like this into the Component, which is inside the MatBottomSheet (here: BottomSheetComponent):
import {MatBottomSheetRef } from '@angular/material/bottom-sheet';

@Component({
...
})
export class BottomSheetComponent {

constructor(private ref: MatBottomSheetRef<BottomSheetComponent>) {}

close() {
this.ref.dismiss()
}

